# Brakeman insufficient validation warning of regex anchors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, ruby-on-rails-4, brakeman

I'm trying to implement a validation in a model like this.

```
validates_format_of :field, with: /[0-9]/, message: 'must have at least one number (0-9)'
```

Brakeman detects this a `Format Validation` security issue and it recommends to add the anchors between the regular expression.

> Insufficient validation for 'field' using /[0-9]/. Use \A and \z as anchors near line 54

If I add those anchors, the regular expression stops working, so I don't know what to do in this case. Here's the tests I made using `rails c`.

```
"asdf1234".match(/\A[0-9]\z/) # => nil
"foobar1".match(/\A[0-9]\z/) # => nil
```

I need that the method return `#<MatchData "1">` in both cases.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to match a string that has at least 1 digit inside, and any other chars before and after, you may use

```
/\A[^0-9]*[0-9].*\z/m
```

or just

```
/\A.*[0-9].*\z/m
```

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `[^0-9]*` - zero or more chars other than an ASCII digit
- `[0-9]` - an ASCII digit
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible, up to the
- `\z` -  end of string.

The `m` modifier makes `.` match any char, including a line break char.

Actually, `/\A.*[0-9].*\z/m` will be a bit slower, as the first `.*` will grab all the string at once and then will backtrack to find the last digit. The first one is more optimized.

Comment: And that will do it, thank you for the solution and the explanation.